# How to return startup type (automatic/manual/disabled) of a Windows service in CMD?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, windows-services, autostart

I want to create a desktop shortcut containing a short command line script in Windows 7 (yes...old) that toggles a certain service from startup type `manual` to `disabled` and back, by running it repeatedly. When going from `manual` to `disabled`, the service should also be terminated, while nothing is done when going from `disabled` to `manual`. Basically, the script should act as a "power on/off" switch for the service in question, like the one on your PC's power supply.

A possible Pythonesque version could look like this:

```py
if service.startup_type = 'manual':
    service.startup_type = 'disabled'
    service.stop()
    print(f'{service.name} disabled.')
    time.sleep(1.0)
else:
    service.startup_type = 'manual'
    print(f'{service.name} enabled.')
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

Note: I would like to use CMD as I'm not familiar with PowerShell yet, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Answered here [windows - How to test whether a service is running from the command line - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353161/how-to-test-whether-a-service-is-running-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample script for you. [Batch script to toggle Windows Update and Trusted Installer services.](https://gist.github.com/hsed/fb6fbe26f1d0cf6d657c35c4a05e1fb9). Replace `wuauserv` with the service of your choice, and remove `TrustedInstaller` references accordingly.

[Backup link](http://web.archive.org/web/20220824184553/https://gist.github.com/hsed/fb6fbe26f1d0cf6d657c35c4a05e1fb9) (Internet Archive)

Answer (score 0):

We all start from somewhere, every day.  ;-}
All you need is in the PowerShell Help Files.

```
Get-Help -Name Get-Service -Full
Get-Help -Name Get-Service -Examples

Get-Help -Name Start-Service -Full
Get-Help -Name Start-Service -Examples

Get-Help -Name Stop-Service -Full
Get-Help -Name Stop-Service -Examples


Get-Service | Select-Object -First 1 | Get-Member

# Results
<#
TypeName: System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController

Name                      MemberType    Definition                                                                                                               
----                      ----------    ----------                                                                                                               
Name                      AliasProperty Name = ServiceName                                                                                                       
RequiredServices          AliasProperty RequiredServices = ServicesDependedOn                                                                                    
Disposed                  Event         System.EventHandler Disposed(System.Object, System.EventArgs)                                                            
Close                     Method        void Close()                                                                                                             
Continue                  Method        void Continue()                                                                                                          
CreateObjRef              Method        System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef CreateObjRef(type requestedType)                                                          
Dispose                   Method        void Dispose(), void IDisposable.Dispose()                                                                               
Equals                    Method        bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                                           
ExecuteCommand            Method        void ExecuteCommand(int command)                                                                                         
GetHashCode               Method        int GetHashCode()                                                                                                        
GetLifetimeService        Method        System.Object GetLifetimeService()                                                                                       
GetType                   Method        type GetType()                                                                                                           
InitializeLifetimeService Method        System.Object InitializeLifetimeService()                                                                                
Pause                     Method        void Pause()                                                                                                             
Refresh                   Method        void Refresh()                                                                                                           
Start                     Method        void Start(), void Start(string[] args)                                                                                  
Stop                      Method        void Stop()                                                                                                              
WaitForStatus             Method        void WaitForStatus(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus desiredStatus), void WaitForStatus(System.ServiceProc...
CanPauseAndContinue       Property      bool CanPauseAndContinue {get;}                                                                                          
CanShutdown               Property      bool CanShutdown {get;}                                                                                                  
CanStop                   Property      bool CanStop {get;}                                                                                                      
Container                 Property      System.ComponentModel.IContainer Container {get;}                                                                        
DependentServices         Property      System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController[] DependentServices {get;}                                                       
DisplayName               Property      string DisplayName {get;set;}                                                                                            
MachineName               Property      string MachineName {get;set;}                                                                                            
ServiceHandle             Property      System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle ServiceHandle {get;}                                                           
ServiceName               Property      string ServiceName {get;set;}                                                                                            
ServicesDependedOn        Property      System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController[] ServicesDependedOn {get;}                                                      
ServiceType               Property      System.ServiceProcess.ServiceType ServiceType {get;}                                                                     
Site                      Property      System.ComponentModel.ISite Site {get;set;}                                                                              
StartType                 Property      System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode StartType {get;}                                                                  
Status                    Property      System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus Status {get;}                                                              
MSDN                      ScriptMethod  System.Object MSDN();                                                                                                    
ToString                  ScriptMethod  System.Object ToString();  
#>
```